# Does a ready-to-use angular-material map component or directive exist?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I'm new to `angular-material` and I cannot find a simple and ready-to-use component that would represent a Google Maps API and, literally, put a map into the DOM. Is there any, or should I mix Angular Material with Google Maps JavaScript API by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, there's not out-of-the-box Angular Material component that would represent Google Maps UI, but it'd be duplicate since an Angular UI component exists that completely encapsulates the Google Maps API (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map). It perfectly fits into Angular Material layout and UI. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exist as part of the Angular Material project, but there's no reason you shouldn't be able to mix with the Google Maps API and build your own.